# Change URL dependent of the active language in Umbraco 7

Tags: url, umbraco, umbraco7

I make a site using Umbraco 7.7 and I've a content tree like below.

[image: Content Tree]

The news *(on image Nieuws)* is made for all language versions *(for now only a Dutch version)* using Vorto.

The problem is the url of the news page. Now it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/data/nieuws
```

I'll like to change this to:

```
http://localhost/nl/nieuws
```

Or if I had an other language:

```
http://localhost/en/news
```

This must also work for the child pages of news. For example:

```
http://localhost/nl/nieuws/nieuwe-directeur
http://localhost/en/news/new-CEO
```

---

I've tried to make a property with alias `umbracoUrlName` but it change only the last part of the URL and it's not possible to create multiple URLs for the same page in other languages.

Here is the result. I've input this text `nl/nieuws` and the URL is changed to this for the news page:

```
http://localhost/data/nlnieuws
```

I've also tried a Vorto editor to for the multiple languages but I've got this url:

```
http://localhost:51086/data/values-nl-benlnieuws-dtdguid36eceba8-82ce-4362-954b-a870c65adfc1/
```

---

How could I change the URL dependent of the actieve language

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create custom `UrlProvider` and `ContentFinder` if you want that.

```
public class DataUrlProvider : IUrlProvider
{
    public virtual string GetUrl(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, int id, Uri current, UrlProviderMode mode)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetOtherUrls(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, int id, Uri current)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DataContentFinder : IContentFinder
{
    public bool TryFindContent(PublishedContentRequest contentRequest)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Implementation is not that complex but not that easy as well and it would be too long for this answer.

To give you an idea how to do it check this blog post:

https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/

Comment: Found an easier answer on the Umbraco forum. Check this link: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/88635-change-url-dependent-of-the-active-language-in-umbraco-7#comment-280214 But thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier answer on the Umbraco forum.

> With Vorto, or anything else really, if you want an URL slug for the language / culture just right-click on the parent node → click *Culture and Hostnames* → select your language → in the domain field put `//mydomain.com/nl/` `/mydomain.com/en/`, etc.
>
> Super easy. It will add it to every page under the node you select.
>
> <sup>Source: [our.umbraco.org forum (*Change URL dependent of the active language in Umbraco 7*)](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/88635-change-url-dependent-of-the-active-language-in-umbraco-7#comment-280214)</sup>